# Is there a way to take the a label, convert it into an int, add 1 then return this value into a string to display it into a label?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a little program that takes care of transactions (see picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqrqc.jpg) And where it sais "Transaction(s) 0" i have to take that zero (which is in a label) and add +1 everytime I click the button "Calculer La Transaction".

Comment: Show us what you have tried please.

Comment: I tried converting my counter to a string (Counter.ToString()) I tried converting my label into an int but I just can't seem to make it work. I want to use a for

ex: For(i = 0; i < MaxValue; i++)

    Label.Text = Label.Text + 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Big thing to do boy, here's a rough stuff!

```
if(int.TryParse(label1.Text, out var value))
{
   value++;
   label1.Text = value.ToString();
}
```

you should show a little effort on searching besides posting straight away on here!

Comment: I'm fairly new to c#, I've only been programming in this language for about  3 months, and only been programming in general for a year. I did do somme research on msdn but nothing proved useful.

Comment: There are many other websites besides MSDN, 3 Months is a fair interval to learn basics of a language.. Anyhow, Hope the Answer Helped You!

Answer (score 0):

```
yourLabel.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(yourLabel.Text) + 1).ToString();
```

Also looking at your comment that you want to use a for loop and change the label each time until you get to maximum. No need to change it every-time in the for loop, you should be using the for loop to get the maximum and then change the label when the for loop is finished.